# Asus A6 won't boot after installation

Tags: 11.10, boot, dual-boot, boot-failure, bootloader

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 (Desctop i386) alongside Window 7.

After installation notebook don't boot: after BIOS loading i see just black screen and blinking cursor and nothing is going on.

If i press and hold SHIFT when notebook is loading, i see message "GRUB loading." and blinking cursor, that's all.

Notebook: Asus A6 1.7GHz PentiumM/RAM 2Gb/HDD 60Gb/ ATI X700 128Mb

I have 1st partition with Win7 (primary, boot), then Ubuntu ext4 (logical), then swap(logical) and another partition NTFS (logical). Ubuntu partition is automatically created by installer.

I tried next actions without success (same result):

- Reinstall GRUB different ways (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling_GRUB2)
- Reverting to GRUB Legacy
  (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling_GRUB2)
- Reinstall with different distributives: "ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso" and "ubuntu-11.10-alternate-i386.iso"
- When i tried "ubuntu-11.10-alternate-i386.iso" second times, i created partition manualy and i made partition for Ubuntu primary and bootable. same result.
- EaseBCD didn't help.
- Check HDD - no errors, no bad sectors.

Now i fix MBR and can boot in Win7 but still i can't load Ubuntu.

Have any tips?

Comment: There's something wrong with Ubuntu 11.10 that keeps some machines (like mine) from booting after installing. :(

Comment: Please file a bug: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs